# Why are my ruby tags not being recognised on js erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sweetalert

The file is saved as application.js.erb
I am trying to use some ruby code as a condition to run my sweet alert.

```
import { initSweetalert } from '../plugins/init_sweetalert';


if (<% !@user.clients.last.present? %>)
initSweetalert('#sweet-alert-location', {
  title: "Location Alert",
  text: "Location can not be changed until you have clicked start",
  icon: "warning"
});
```

The ruby tags are not being recognised in my code

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
<% !@user.clients.last.present? %>
```

with

```
<%= !@user.clients.last.present? %>
```

You forgot **equal sign**

Comment: Hi I am actually not looking for my code to be shown just to check if a condition is present so there is no need for an equals sign . The ruby tags are failing to be recognised in the js erb file. So even if I dont want my code to be show it still would not be working

Comment: the problem is in fact application js can not be changed to js.erb as it is part of webpacker

Comment: whatever your result comes from this !@user.clients.last.present? that is true or false, unless you embed that to your js file which will be by putting an equal sign in the ruby tags, unless you do that, true/false will not be embedded in the if () condition